# Argument of Feynman for equivalence of dot product definitions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following argument from the Feynman Lectures on Physics ([Vol I, Lecture 11](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_11.html)), which relates to the equivalence of the algebraic and geometric definitions, does not particularly convince me.

> Also, there is a simple geometrical way to calculate $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$, without
> having to calculate the components of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$: $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ is the product of
> the length of $\vec{a}$ and the length of $\vec{b}$ times the cosine of the angle
> between them. Why? Suppose that we choose a special coordinate system
> in which the x-axis lies along $\vec{a}$; in those circumstances, the only
> component of $\vec{a}$ that will be there is $a_x$, which is of course the whole
> length of $\vec{a}$. Thus Eq. (11.19) reduces to $a \cdot b = a_x b_x$ for this case, and
> this is the length of $\vec{a}$ times the component of $\vec{b}$ in the direction of
> $\vec{a}$, that is, $b \cos \theta$: $a \cdot b = a b \cos \theta$. Therefore, in that special coordinate
> system, we have proved that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ is the length of $\vec{a}$ times the length of
> $\vec{b}$ times $\cos \theta$. But if it is true in one coordinate system, it is true
> in all, **because $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ is independent of the coordinate system**; that is
> our argument.

In fact, most of this argument seems just fine, but it seems like Feynman is casually asserting *a priori* that the dot product should be independent of the coordinate system. This is something I do not like, since I can't see an obvious justification for it. (Indeed, if by "coordinate system" he means basis, then there are clearly bases for which this is not true, e.g., ${2\hat{i}, 2\hat{j}, 2\hat{k}}$.)

Could someone who is better at reading between the lines of Feynman please clarify this for me?

Comment: I'm guessing that he means that $a\cdot b$ is unchanged if you apply a rigid rotation to the coordinate system, which is accomplished by multiplying $a$ and $b$ by some orthogonal matrix $R$ (which by definition satisfies $R^T R = I$). In that case, the dot product of $Ra$ and $Rb$ is the same as $a \cdot b$, because $(Ra) \cdot (Rb) = (Ra)^T(Rb) = a^T R^T R b = a^T b = a \cdot b$. But I could be misinterpreting what he is saying.

Comment: @Bungo That would make sense, though I would expect something more intuitive given Feynman (I imagine) would not assume such a significant amount of linear algebra is under the belt of the student at this point -- and perhaps none at all. Perhaps he is genuinely hand-waving though?

Comment: If you limit you "choose of coordinate system" to mean rigid motions ... $SO_2,$ or $SO_3$  this argument will hold.

Comment: Yep, so it seems. @littleO left a good answer below along the lines of what you or Bungo suggested, so I'm thinking Feynman meant this, but simply didn't want to touch the maths. (And unfortunately, he doesn't seem to offer intuition to fill in the gap, on this rare occasion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem to be a gap in the argument. Maybe Feynman filled in the gap elsewhere, or maybe it's a true gap. He's a physicist so he's not aiming for full mathematical rigor, he just wants great insight.

Here's how I would fill in the gap. Suppose that $\beta = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Let $Q = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \end{bmatrix}$ (so the $i$th column of $Q$ is the column vector $u_i$). The change of basis matrix from the standard basis to $\beta$ is $Q^{-1} = Q^T$.

Now suppose that $x$ and $y$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. Notice that
\begin{align}
 (Q^T x) \cdot (Q^T y ) &= (Q^T x)^T Q^T y \\
&= x^T Q Q^T y \\
&= x^T y \\
&= x \cdot y.
\end{align}
This shows that changing basis from the standard basis to the basis $\beta$ does not change the dot product.

Comment: This seems like the most reasonable explanation. I think Feynman must have been just hand-waving a bit, given his target audience and the fact he's trying to teach physics and not maths. Still, it begs the question why he bothers trying to show the two definitions are equivalent to begin with without at least offering intuition (if not proof). It's a bit uncharacteristic of him. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure it's totally out of character. The argument given is at least a very quick and effortless way to recover the formula $a \cdot b = \| a \| \| b \| \cos(\theta)$, if one happens to forget the expression on the right. If you read The Feynman Tips on Physics (recommended!) there's a part where he draws sort of a graph showing how knowledge is interconnected, to illustrate how if you forget one fact you can rederive it using related facts. One thing that was striking to me about his picture, and maybe revealed something about Feynman's mindset, is that the graph he drew was not a tree.

Comment: Well, I'd say it would be more in his character if he had given some sort of intuition as to why the dot product shouldn't change. As it stands, I feel there's too big a hole to make it a derivation. Fair point about the rest!

Answer (score 2):

There is missing context in your question and the other answers are all missing the point IMO.

Feynman's definition of a vector is three numbers that transform like a **step in space** does under rotation of coördinate axes.
In other words three numbers that transform according to the following laws (you can work this out geometrically):

```
x' = xcos(θ) + ysin(θ)
y' = ycos(θ) - xsin(θ)
z' = z
```

What Feynman does prior to your paragraph is proving that A ° B is invariant (does not change) under rotation.The paragraph you showed here, he talks about a way to calculate the *length* in a simple way. By that point he has already showed that $A °B$ is invariant.

He does this in the following way:

First he shows that the length of a vector is invariant under rotation of coördinate axes.
(In general it's often convenient to work with the square of a quantity when there is a square root involved, this is a general technique and is not the essence here.)

The square of the length of a vector in the rotated axes:

$x' ^2 + y' ^2 + z' ^2$

We wish to know what this quantity which we call "the length" is in terms of the coördinates of the non rotated axes. That is, what do we have to do to the "non-prime" coördinates to get this same quantity?

If we substitute the above transformation, we get:

$$(xcos(θ) + ysin(θ))^2 + (y(cosθ) -xsin(θ))^2 + z ^2 =
x^2 (cos^2(θ) + sin^2(θ)) + 2xcos(θ)ysin(θ) + y^2 (sin^2(θ) + cos^2(θ))
-2ycos(θ)sin() + z ^2 = 
x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$

(using $cos^2(θ) + sin^2(θ) = 1$ and cancellation of terms)

So we see that to get the same quantity, you do the same with x,y,z as with
x',y',z'. So we say " the length (which is adding of squares in both coördinate systems) of a vector is invariant under rotation of the coördinate axes."

He defines this "square of length quantity" $Ax^2 + Ay^2 + Az^2$ as $A ° A$.

*Only then*, *using this* does he show the invariance of A ° B in the following way:

He defines the following vector $C = A + B$

If you apply the previously obtained to this you get:

$C ° C = (Ax + Bx)^2 + (Ay + By)^2 + (Az + Bz)^2 = A ° A + B ° B + 2(AxBx + AyBy + AzBz)$

Since all other terms are constant when changing coördinate axes, this last term is also constant. Of course, you could get the same result in a less tricky way by proving this with the transformation above, just like you proved A ° A. But since you already proved that, this is an elegant way to proof A ° B. I'm pretty sure if you did it via the transformation, you could discover this "trick" by yourself. Another way of understanding this trick is that you know you are going to need an equation in terms of Ax,Bx and so forth and you know you're going to want something in your equation which stays constant. So if you have A + B, that takes care of the components and to then have "something constant" you remember the $A ° A$ thing. This way you *might* have come with the idea to try $(A + B) ° (A + B)$.

Then he ***uses*** this fact in the paragraph of your question.

Feynman is not that "intuïtive" IMO.
He's always correct, very mathematical, very abstract, idiosyncratic, ...
The important thing to realize about Feynman is what he's doing is secretly recapitulating history. He read the principia for instance and (partly) redid it his own way.

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly that you're looking for a justification that the two computations are equivalent, I came up with a way to demonstrate this a few months ago. Myself, I always found the geometric $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = ||\vec{a}|| \cos(θ) ||\vec{b}||$ computation to be the more intuitive, so I'll start with that definition and justify the element-based definition. This won't require anything more than basic trig and some geometric intuitions.

Say we have 2 vectors, $ \vec{u} $ and $ \vec{v} $, in $ \mathbb{R}^n$, and let's assume that these vectors are non-collinear-- one isn't a scaled up version of the other (if they are collinear, then cos(θ) = 1 which simplifies the problem considerably). Explicitly,
$$\vec{u}=<u_1,u_2,u_3,\cdots,u_n>$$
$$\vec{v}=<v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots,v_n>$$
If they aren't collinear, and if their tails lie at the origin of our n-dimensional space, then we can use their positions two define two lines: one line going between  the origin and $\vec{u}$, and another line going through the origin and $\vec{v}$. The great thing about this setup is that now we're dealing with 3 points in space. It doesn't matter how many dimensions those points may exist in according to our axes, because 3 points is enough to define a unique plane in that space. We don't know how to label those points in that plane, but we know those points exist in it. Turning to GeoGebra,
[image: Graph of 2 vectors in a plane]
I've labeled the coordinate points in context of our n-dimensional space-- we're not using the 2D coordinates of the plane itself. Now, we know we want to connect this element computation to geometry. To do that, I've labeled θ, the angle between the two vectors in the plane that contains them, and I've defined a vector $$\vec{w} = \vec{v}-\vec{u}$$
$$\vec{w} = <v_1 - u_1, v_2 - u_2, v_3 - u_3, \cdots, v_n - u_n>$$
We notice that this diagram draws out a triangle, and, if we assume we know θ as well as our two vectors, we get the triangle
[image: triange]
And now we do some math.

It's not guranteed that our vectors will produce a right triangle, so to solve this thing we'll need the Law of Cosines, as well as the magnitudes of the sides of our triangle.
$$\text{Law of Cosines:} \: \: c^2 = a^2 +b^2 - 2ab\cos(\angle C)$$
$$ ||\vec{u}|| = \sqrt{u^2_1 + u^2_2 + u^2_3 + \cdots + u^2_n}$$
$$ ||\vec{v}|| = \sqrt{v^2_1 + v^2_2 + v^2_3 + \cdots + v^2_n}$$
$$ ||\vec{w}|| = \sqrt{(v_1 - u_1)^2 + (v_2 - u_2)^2 + (v_3 - u_3)^2 + \cdots + (v_n - u_n)^2}$$
If our side $a$ is represented by $\vec{u}$, and side $b$ is represented by $\vec{v}$, then side $c$ and $\angle C$ are given by $\vec{w}$ and $θ$. Using these values in the Law of Cosines formula and solving this for $\cos(θ)$ gives
$$\cos(\angle C) = -\frac{c^2 - a^2 - b^2}{2ab}$$
$$\cos(θ) = -\frac{||\vec{w}||^2 - ||\vec{u}||^2 - ||\vec{v}||^2}{2||\vec{u}|||\vec{v}||}$$
$$\cos(θ) = -\frac{[(v_1 - u_1)^2 + (v_2 - u_2)^2 + \cdots + (v_n - u_n)^2] - [u^2_1 + u^2_2 + \cdots + u^2_n] - [v^2_1 + v^2_2 + \cdots + v^2_n]}{2||\vec{u}|||\vec{v}||}$$
Expanding out our terms for $||\vec{w}||^2$,

$$\cos(θ) = -\frac{
[v_1^2 - 2 u_1 v_1 + u_1^2 + v_2^2 - 2 u_2 v_2 + u_2^2 + \cdots + v_n^2 - 2 u_n v_n + u_n^2]
 - [u^2_1 + u^2_2 + \cdots + u^2_n] - [v^2_1 + v^2_2 + \cdots + v^2_n]}{2||\vec{u}|||\vec{v}||}$$
It is at this point we notice that every $u_i^2$ and $v_i^2$ in the numerator has a corresponding $-u_i^2$ and $-v_i^2$, allowing us to reduce all those terms to $0$. Doing this, along with distributing the negatives across, gives us
$$\cos(θ) = \frac{2 u_1 v_1 + 2 u_2 v_2 + \cdots + 2 u_n v_n}{2||\vec{u}|||\vec{v}||}$$
$$\cos(θ) = \frac{ u_1 v_1 +  u_2 v_2 + \cdots +  u_n v_n}{||\vec{u}|||\vec{v}||}$$
Tying all of this back to our given definition for the dot product
$$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = ||\vec{u}||\cos(θ)||\vec{v}||$$
$$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = ||\vec{u}||||\vec{v}||\frac{ u_1 v_1 +  u_2 v_2 + \cdots +  u_n v_n}{||\vec{u}|||\vec{v}||}$$
$$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = u_1 v_1 +  u_2 v_2 + \cdots +  u_n v_n$$
Hopefully that gives an intuitive path for how we would go about connecting those two computations.